# "Can't execute sync rule for source column" when editing SQLAlchemy data with Flask-Admin

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I have some SQLAlchemy models for a mesh of nodes and metrics for each node.  My goal is to use Flask-Admin to show and edit all the information on one page. This works great for display, as it shows me a `mesh` column in the Metric list.

I need to be able to change the `Mesh` object for my `Metric`'s `Node`. On the Flask-Admin "Metric list" page, it shows me the mesh options to select, but then on update I get the following error:

> Failed to update record. Failed to update record. Can't execute sync rule for source column 'Metric.node_id'; mapper 'Mapper|Metric|metric' does not map this column. Try using an explicit `foreign_keys` collection which does not include destination column 'metric.node_id' (or use a `viewonly=True` relation).

How can I edit the `Mesh` associated with a `Metric` from Flask-Admin?

```
class Mesh(Base):
   id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
   mesh_type = Column(Integer)
   mesh_name = Column(String(255))

class Node(Base):
   node_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
   mesh_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Mesh.id))

   mesh = relationship('Mesh', backref='node')

class Metric(Base):
   node_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Node.node_id), primary_key=True)

   node = relationship('Node', uselist=False)
   mesh = relationship('Mesh', uselist=False, secondary=Node.__table__)
```